# Android studio SDK manager is not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Java 8. And I have set the home variable. But I got this error. I am using Windows 7 64-bit.

[image]

I am new to android programming. Please help.

Comment: once open `cmd` and check `javac -version` is working or giving error

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `JAVA_HOME` variable. Refer to this post, if you're not sure how you can do that: [Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)

[image: JAVA_HOME variable settings]