# Failed to sync gradle project in android studio "Please configure the JDK to match the expected one"

Tags: android

I am new to Android Studio. I installed Android Studio v1.2.2 and I have jdk1.7.0_80 installed.

I am facing a problem with Gradle build.

I am getting the following error message:

> Error:The newly created daemon process has a different context than
>   expected. Java home is different. Expecting: 'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre' but was: 'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80'. Please configure the JDK to match the
>   expected one.

Comment: Configure your JDK like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)

Comment: My JAVA-HOME is already set but still i m getting this error.

Comment: **MODIFY default Boot JDK** Friendly link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/57193266/6897913