# Why I can't install Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[Error Details HERE !!!](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/+UrvishPatelCEO/albums/6183197806102042449/6183197811429131954?sqi=105153134372062985968&sqsi=d830bd5d-0a65-42f3-8095-006544c1ef34&pid=6183197811429131954&oid=113816842210147237034)
What is this ??
I've already set Environment Variable,Installed JDK, even restarted laptop.but still not installing !

SYSTEM Details

Android Studio Version :: android-studio-bundle-135.1641136
Operating System :: Windows 7 64-bit
Laptop : Lenovo g500

Comment: Have you tried the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)? Also, FWIW, I never had much luck using Android Studio on Windows. Slow emulator and a host of minor issues. Everything became much simpler when I gave up and installed it on my Linux partition instead.

Comment: You should include images directly in your question. Links are generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear that you either don't have Java JDK installed (maybe you installed only JRE) or you have a wrong version (might be an old version). Install latest JDK from Oracle and try again. Make sure you set the JAVA_HOME correctly. The Oracle installer doesn't do that AFAIK.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR RESPONSE ! GOD BLESS YOU ! 
I have already installed it !(latest java version) and also set environment variable ! again & again . but till ...