# Android Studio doesn't find Java Development Kit (JDK)

Tags: java, android-studio, java-8, windows-10

I have installed `Java 8` on my computer but `Android Studio` doesn't find it. When I execute the installer of `Android Studio` I only can see an screen in which I can see an introduction and when I press "Next" another screen it's displayed in which says:

> We could not detect a Java Development Kit (JDK) v7 or newer on your system. Please browse to its path if known.

So I searched my `JDK` and when I press the button "Next" I get the following message:

> Sorry, we still could not detect a valid JDK, which we need to proceed.
>
> If setting your JDK path manually, make sure you have browsed to a parent directory that contains a "bin\java.exe" whose version reports 1.7 or higher when you run "java.exe -version".

After that, I go to the console and execute the command "java.exe -version". It gives to me:

> java version "1.8.0_60"

So I don't know why it doesn't find my `JDK`. I also tried adding some Environment Variables:

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\
JDK_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\
```

But it still doesn't find it. How can I fix it?

**Note:** I'm using `Windows 10` as OS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `JDK_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60` is there a typo? You have set `jdk` path to `jre` folder

Comment: I saw JDK_HOME here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found

Comment: but you point to `JRE1.8..` folder. You should install Java 8 Development Kit, not Java 8 Runtime Environment. These are two different things

Comment: @wasyl I will look at it now and I answer to you if it works. Thanks for the point!

Comment: @wasyl Thank you very much! Reinstalling Java the folder `jdk` appeared and I could point to it in my `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your JAVA_HOME variable is set to the wrong thing.  Mine is:

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

I also have a PATH variable set as follows:

```
PATH      %JAVA_HOME%\BIN
```

I do not have a JDK_HOME variable.

Try that and see if it works.

(I recently installed Android Studio and had the same problem, even though I had Java 7 installed.  So I downloaded Java 8 and manually updated the JAVA_HOME variable.)

Comment: Thanks for the point! I will see it now and answer to you if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much! Before I didn't have the folder  `jdk`, only the `jre` so I unistall Java and reinstall it again and now I put the new folder `jdk` on my `JDK_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to install Android Studio bundle v2.1 (143.2915827-windows) on a Windows 10 machine with a JDK at a non-standard location (the JDK on a path containing spaces). After manually selecting the path, the installer would complain that it could still not find a JDK. I solved it by manually enclosing the selected path with double quotes by typing in the editable textbox.

Answer (score 0):

This drove me nuts for a couple of days. I was not able to resolve the issue through the Android studio installer, but found a workaround:

- Go to http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
- Instead of downloading "Android Studio package" (the exe file), scroll down and select "SDK tools package" (the zip file).
- This work perfectly and allows you to select all the packages you want to download, including the packages installed by the installer.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me. I recieved the same error message and went to directly install the java, without closing the installation of Android studio. then tried to find the path. so I closed out the window for Android Studio and Reopened the download file and it automatically detected it. This might not work for everyone but worth a try. easier then messing with everthing else.