# Error installing Android Studio, JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: java, android, installation, environment-variables

Just tried installing Android Studio and I got the error:

The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;) does not point to a valid JVM installation. What does this mean? I write java code everyday on eclipse and everything runs fine.

Comment: lmgtfy...  Really, is googling this not easier than typing it up as a question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)

Comment: This question has been asked many times as people new to programming tend to have this issue

Answer (score 0):

This means that java is not setup in your windows path. Eclipse does not require this but many things do.

EDIT: here is the page on the java website explaining this in detail with instructions per OS: https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Answer (score 0):

Check your system, Java and Android Studio all is same version like 32bit or 64bit. its may be your system is 64bit and your java is 32bit then it's install in `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin` and ur android studio is 64bit and its finding Java from `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin` so check your system, Java and Android Studio all is same like 32bit or 64bit