# Android Studio Java JDK error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to learn to make Java Android applications in Android Studio, 
I downloaded both the Java JDK and Android studio on an external drive (D:).
I'm getting this error on start-up:

tools.jar seems to be not in Studio classpath.

Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.

So I already searched Stackoverflow for the same error, but my Java folder seems to be a little bit different (it makes me wonder if I downloaded the correct JDK).
Because the advice was to either move tools.jar or change the value of JAVA_HOME.
None of those are an option because i can't seem to find the JDK in the Java folder. (D:\Java)
Did I install the wrong JDK?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the `JAVA_HOME` variable set correctly?

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16574700?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21 doesnt exist on my computer. D:\Java\jdk1.7.0_21 neither..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Download JDK: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

2) Android Studio -> File -> Project structure -> JDK location. Point at where you have installed it.

Comment: Oh i downloaded jdk7 for some reason.. Thanks i'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: 7 should work too, you just need to find it on your disk :)

Comment: It seems to work now! Thanks alot for the link Reizen :)