# I can't install Android Studio (JDK can't be found)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't install Android Studio because when I start the installation, 
it can't detect a JDK. When I set manually the path (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`) and click Next, it says that he still could not detect a valid JDK. I have done what it asks: verify the version with `java.exe -version` and this is OK, I have a good version (1.7). I have also try with a 1.8 version, but it didn't work either.

I have tried everything I've found :

- set the environment variables : `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` to `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79"` and `PATH` to `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin"` (and I have placed it before `"C:\Windows\System32"`)
- uninstall all JDK and reinstall just one.
- I have verified that my configuration matches the minimum system requirements (and it's OK).
- The Virtualization Technology is enabled.

And I need to mention that I had Android Studio installed on my computer (it worked perfectly, and I didn't had any problem to install it the first time) but I had to uninstall it. I did it properly (with the "uninstall a program" in the control panel). After that, before trying to reinstall it, I have empty the trash and clean the registry with CCleaner.

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Comment: very good question, fully explained :)

Comment: i think your JDK is not properly installed,  you should reinstall JDK and then install Android Studio, I often install reinstall Android Studio but I had never faced this issue.

Comment: @Anders hmmm OP stated he uninstalled all JDK and installed just one, could it be a permission issue ?

Comment: Yes, congratulations for your patience in explaining all the scenario. I would suggest you to down a brand new copy of A.S. installation package. Maybe the matter you're facing relates with an old A.S. version confliting with a new version of JDK. Try this: unninstall all; install the newest JDK; do a full restart of Windows; install the newest A.S. Hope you solve this soon. @niceman is right, check about permissions.

Comment: No I don't think its permissions issue, have you tried solution on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found?rq=1) page? there are multiple on there

Comment: @Anders I have tried to uninstall/reinstall but it didn't worked and also none of the solutions of the page you give me worked. Each time I have the same problem.

Comment: @statosdotcom I have tried this twice (I have downloaded the latest versions on the official website) but it didn't worked. I have always the same problem. I have also checked the permissions and I don't think it's the problem. And one more thing : when I do (in cmd.exe) "where java", it displays the right path "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/bin/java.exe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an alternative solution to my problem:

- download and install IntelliJ IDEA (the IDE): https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/
- download and install android SDK tools package (not Android Studio).
- download and install the latest JDK (or at least a 1.7 version).
- download Gradle (binary): http://gradle.org/gradle-download/
- run the SDK manager as an Administrator (in C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk) and install the default packages.
- run IntelliJ IDEA (as an Administrator) and on the bottom right corner click on **Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure**. On the left panel, go to **SDKs** and add (with the **+** sign) **JDK** (select the JDK folder. It's "jdk1.8.0_11" for me and usually it's in C:/Program Files/Java). Also add **Android SDK** (C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk). Click on **Apply** and **OK**.
- create a new project.
- to resolve errors with Gradle, go to **File -> Settings**. On the left panel, go to **Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle**. Select "Use local gradle distribution" (and set the path of gradle). Check the box "Offline work".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue once. It was due to the fact that I had a x64 version of JDK and x32 version of Android Studio. Check that you are using the same version of those and it's the correct version for your OS.

Comment: How can I know if the link on the official website to download A.S. is in x32 or x64 ? There is no specification about that. My OS and my JDK are in x64.

Comment: I checked on the website and it seems that now Android Studio comes only on one version. If you are still having the same issue, could you try using a JDK 7 instead of 8?

Comment: I have already tried with both versions of JDK and it didn't work. I have the same error.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I use Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: This is very strange... I'd suggest you to uninstall both the JDK and AS once more and reinstall them with right click -> Run as Administrator... Let me know if that does anything...

Comment: I have already do that, but I did it one more time and it does nothing.

Comment: When you have to set the path of JDK are you doing it manually or are you using the Browse... button? To which directory are you pointing?

Comment: I use the browse button and the path is : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

Comment: Can you try doing java -version on command prompt and write back the output? Thank you.