# "Setup SDK" error display in new android studio 2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I just download the newest Android Studio from the developer site.

After installation I installed Android Studio, then I created new project and after project build completed, I opened my `MainActivity.java` file to find this error. Please refer to screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

I also downloaded Android SDK component which is built-in already in Android Studio.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? ( Build > Clean Project ) ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found

Answer (score 1):

Start Android Studio and invalidate cache File--> Invalidate Cache and Restart.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rebuild your project. Try clean build. That should do. Faced a similar problem.

Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Build -> Rebuild

2. Incorrect installation of JDK also might cause problems. Please tell what the error is in detail.
3. You can try this for JDK Installation:-

On some Windows systems, the launcher script does not find where the JDK is installed. If you encounter this problem, you need to set an environment variable indicating the correct location.
Select Start menu > Computer > System Properties > Advanced System Properties. Then open Advanced tab > Environment Variables and add a new system variable JAVA_HOME that points to your JDK folder, for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77.

Comment: i tried your all suggestion and also restart studio and sync file and jdk installation but the error is still occurred

Comment: Try updating your Android SDK. If you have the latest SDK. Reinstall the SDK and try.

Answer (score 0):

Goto `File -> Project Structure` on left hand side click on `SDK Location` there you can find `Android SDK Location` and `JDK Location`. So, now locate your `JDK` path by browsing your `JDK` installation path. Click `OK`, Now goto `Build -> Rebulid` your project.

It's better to check whether the `JDK` path set in Environment variable by typing `java -version` in `commmand prompt`. If it is not set, set the path as DvD said in his [*post*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582578/setup-sdk-error-display-in-new-android-studio-2-1-1/37583150#37583150).

Hope this works for you.