# android studio does not open : Could not load main class com/intellij/idea/main

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I installed **Android studio** a month ago and it worked successfully and i was using **windows 7(64bit)** then i setup a new **windows 7 (32bit)** and i reinstalled the JDK and Android Studio but it didn't work ,, first a massage pop up to set **environment variables** which i did then i opened it again and another message appeared "**Could not load main class com/intellij/idea/main**" i searched about that problem and found that the solution is to add **JAVA_HOME** with value "**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101**" then i opened it again and it didn't work and no messages appeared .. what is the solution ?

Comment: you should search these kind of problems on net at least once before putting here . try to make sure compatible jdk 32bit with studio.exe (not studio64.exe) ,Environment variables  or if nothing works , reinstall

Comment: i said that i searched about it but the problem hasn't been solved ,, can u tell me more details please ? ,, i installed JDK 32 bit ,, and i run android studio from studio.exe not studio64

Comment: usually it happens because of INVALID JAVA_HOME variable so make sure it is pointing to correct installed java ,otherwise you can wait for some better answer if you don't want to reinstall the IDE

Comment: i installed the latest JDK 1.8.0_101 and i reinstalled too but still having the same problem

Comment: no buddy i didn't tell you to reinstall jdk ,the problem could be either with JAVA_HOME path in you environment variable or something went wrong with studio installation

Comment: for JAVA_HOME , i added a new variable in user variables with value "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101" and for Android studio i reinstalled it too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)