# I am getting error improperly specified VM option on Android IDE

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ide

I just installed new version of Android IDE today on my

> D:\program file\Android

and installed java 1.5.0_6 JDK on **C drive**. I pointed out this path in a system environment

> JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_06\    ( user veriable)
>
> JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_06\jre\bin\javaw.exe  ( system veriable)

after that image getting an error please check this image..
[image]

Comment: Explain why are you installing a JDK that is [End Of Life](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_5_eol.xml) for more than 10 years?

Comment: because when i completed and run IDE then it starts asking about VM. I l am PHP developer. so no need of java. so i never used JDK form 10 years...  only used for PHPStrom because that asks this.

Comment: Please go through [Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16574189/295004) and if still not working update your question with OS version and what steps you tried.

Comment: thanks to your comment.. i have installed a new version of JDK-8  update-241 to parent site.. i hope it will work for me.

Answer (score 7):

If you added some custom `vmoptions` then you can simply edit them with proper versions or better delete them.

go to
`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudiox.x`

and spot the file named

`studio64.exe.vmoptions`

If you know how to edit it correctly which depends on the version of Android Studio, JDK and other aspects then edit it, in my case I just deleted it.

Restart your Android Studio.

Comment: In my case my JAVA_HOME was set to use JRE(Java Runtime Environment) instead of the required JDK(Java Development Kit, more tooling than JRE). I just downloaded JDK 8 and updated my JAVA_HOME. JDK8 https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

Comment: Thanks for commenting and improving the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was using old JDK. so that i was getting error. so use JDK-1.8.*  for fix this problem. In my case i tried many versions then i got success 1.8.