# Android studio error launching : could not find main class com / intellij/ idea / main

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am new to android studio; as a matter of fact I just downloaded the recommended package. For more context, I am a windows 7 user and the 64 bit isn't executable in my system, so the right launcher is studio.exe and studio64.exe can't serve as an alternative. I downloaded the 7 jdk and set a path for it. Now here comes the issue: whenever I click on the android icon, this launching error comes up : could not find main class com / intellij/ idea / main. I surfed through answers and websites and tried the following with no success : -eliminate second copies / -uninstall and reinstall / -make sure boostrap.jre in lib file is present. So if you please have some other solution than the tried ones above, please comment below . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uninstall Android studio then go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio and clear all. Reinstall.

Comment: @mycky thank you for your reply mycky, however, I tried this method already. Can you please look at the tried methods I mentioned and see if you can come up with another solution?

Comment: Share your project structure and run configuration you are using. It is more project-related error rather than IDE-related. Recreating the project from scratch could fix that.

Comment: maybe a classpath missing watch this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found correct classpath than reinstall

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found